# How to add 'slideUp' effect to 'toggle' function within 'click' index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a dynamic Model->Submodel category selector on an ecommerce website (host by BigCommerce). I have designed a stencil structure to build the pages out with their "children". The "Models" are shown with a click function to show "submodels" below them in a row. I had a friend help with the script to adjust the way the sub-models were displayed and organized. I wanted to add a toggle function so clicking on the same Model would toggle/collapse the Submodel section.

Adding a toggle function to the 'const' if condition worked, but I cannot get the 'slideUp' effect to trigger with it. 
I tested:
"existingSubmodel.toggle().slideUp(400);"
and
"existingSubmodel.slideUp(400, () => {existingSubmodel.toggle();});". Neither worked for me.

```js
$().ready(() => {

  // Any time a model is clicked, do the following.
  $(".model").click((e) => {
    const existingSubmodel = $('.sub-models.active');
    if (existingSubmodel.get(0)) {
      //Finish any animations if there are some going on. 
      existingSubmodel.stop(true, true);
      // Wait until the submodels have finshed sliding up and then remove. 
      existingSubmodel.slideUp(400, () => {
        existingSubmodel.remove();
      });
      existingSubmodel.toggle();
    }
    addSubmodels(e);
  });
});

/**
 * Find the index of the model
 * Then find the position in the row (ie what column is it?)
 * Then find the index to insert at - this will be at the end of a row so that the submodels container will start on a new line. 
 * Create a clone of the submodel container and add an `.active` class to it. 
 * Append that submodel clone to the `indexToInsert`.
 * Slide it down. 
 */
function addSubmodels(e) {
  const parent = $(e.currentTarget);
  const parentId = parent.attr('id');
  const index = getIndexOfElement(parent);
  const position = getPositionInFlex(parent);
  const indexToInsert = index + getNumberOfElements() - position;

  const elementToAppendTo = $(".model").get(indexToInsert);
  const subModel = $("#submodel-" + parentId).clone(true);
  subModel.addClass('active');
  $(elementToAppendTo).after(subModel);
  $('.sub-models.active').slideDown(400);
}

function getIndexOfElement(element) {
  return $('.model').toArray().findIndex(e => {
    return e.id === element.attr('id');
  });
}

function getNumberOfElements() {
  return Math.floor($("#container").width() / $(".model").outerWidth(true));
}

function getPositionInFlex(element) {
  const numEl = getNumberOfElements();
  const index = getIndexOfElement(element) + 1;
  const position = index % numEl;
  return position === 0 ? numEl : position;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: white;
}

.model {
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.model:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #AAA;
}

.model-text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #AAA;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sub-models {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.sub-model-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sub-model {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.hide {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  Select From The Following Models
</h1>
<!-- Grandparent -->
<div id="container">
  <div id="1" class="model">

    <div class="model-text">
      Model 1
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="2" class="model">
    <div class="model-text">
      Model 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="model">
    <div class="model-text">
      Model 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="model">
    <div class="model-text">
      Model 4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="5" class="model">
    <div class="model-text">
      Model 5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="6" class="model">
    <div class="model-text">
      Model 6
    </div>

  </div>


  <div id="submodel-1" class="sub-models">
    <div class="sub-model-row">
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 1
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 2
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="submodel-2" class="sub-models">
    <div class="sub-model-row">
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 2 SubModel 1
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 2 SubModel 2
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 2 SubModel 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="submodel-3" class="sub-models">
    <div class="sub-model-row">
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 3 SubModel 1
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 3 SubModel 2
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 3 SubModel 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="submodel-4" class="sub-models">
    <div class="sub-model-row">
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 1
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 2
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="submodel-5" class="sub-models">
    <div class="sub-model-row">
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 1
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 2
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="submodel-6" class="sub-models">
    <div class="sub-model-row">
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 1
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 2
      </div>
      <div class="sub-model">
        Model 1 SubModel 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just need the toggle function to animate with the slideUp effect. It would be great if the switching 'Submodel' sections would trigger the slide up animation as well (which it does if you remove the "existingSubmodel.toggle();" code from JS line 13. Any help would be appreciated as I'm still learning jQuery and my JS is so so.

You can play with it here also: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markdorman/nud3kaez/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your primary goal is just to make sure that the sub-model toggles if the model it's under is clicked, then you can remove the `toggle()` or `slideToggle()` function as it exists here. 
Instead you can do something like so after the `if (existingSubmodel.get(0))` block:

```
// Add .activemodel class to each model-text that gets clicked. 
// If the model-text has the activemodel class already, just remove it and do nothing else. 
// Otherwise, add the new submodel in there, AND get rid of all .activemodel classes, 
// and just add a new .activemodel class on the the model that is now active.  


if ($(e.target).hasClass('activemodel')) {
    $(e.target).removeClass('activemodel');
} else {
    addSubmodels(e);
    $('.activemodel').removeClass('activemodel');
    $(e.target).addClass('activemodel');
}
```

I noticed that this will also fail if the final row is not full, this is probably a minor oversight by your friend - `indexToInsert` is calculated as if the row is full. If it's not full, then `elementToAppendTo` will not actually exist so you can't append to it. I think a decent solution here would be to reset `indexToInsert` to the the last index of `$('.models')` if it ends up being longer than that last index. That might look something like this:

```
// after setting const position
const models = $(".model");
let indexToInsert = index + getNumberOfElements() - position;
if (indexToInsert > models.length-1) { indexToInsert = models.length-1}

const elementToAppendTo = models.get(indexToInsert);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I actually just noticed that issue as well and you saved me a bunch of time by providing that solution. Taking this as the best answer. Thank you! Working fiddle for anyone who would like to see it can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/markdorman/v6m24q0e/6/

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

After playing with this in a fiddle I could see what you were actually trying to achieve. slideUp is really the method you want, but you need to specify the correct element in the dom tree, because you're cloning the element: `existingSubmodel[0].slideUp();` Here, we specify the first element in the dom tree because you're appending the clone.

```
  // Any time a model is clicked, do the following.
  $(".model").click((e) => {
    const existingSubmodel = $('.sub-models.active');
    if (existingSubmodel.get(0)) {
        //Finish any animations if there are some going on. 
        existingSubmodel.stop(true,true);
        // Wait until the submodels have finshed sliding up and then remove. 
        existingSubmodel.slideUp(400, () => {
           existingSubmodel.remove(); 
        });
        existingSubmodel[0].slideUp(); 
    }
    addSubmodels(e);
  });
```

And the rest of your code is good. Really all I changed was line 13.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mcpdnyaz/1/#&togetherjs=1SSm3yLPeh

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might have not worded things correctly in my original question of what I was going for. This does trigger the slideUp when clicking the original "Model", but it no longer switches between them when clicking on a new "Model". That's why I was hoping to do it with a toggle type command so clicking on the current Model would slideUp the current Submodel and clicking on a new Model would slideUp the current Model and slideDown the new Submodel.